The Sublime Text package "rainbow_csv" has the wrong color palette
I've installed the Sublime Text Package "rainbow_csv", but the colors are all wrong.
It's not "rainbow" at all - just muddy colors, with a grey that blends into the background like a comment. And white appears redundantly for both the 1st and 3rd column.

So I want to customize the palette.
I've tried following the instructions in the GitHub repo, but nothing changes.
RainbowCSV.sublime-settings ↓
// Use custom high-contrast rainbow colors instead of colors provided by your current color scheme. 
// When you enable this option, "auto_adjust_rainbow_colors" also gets enabled by default.
"use_custom_rainbow_colors": true,


// Auto adjust rainbow colors for Packages/User/RainbowCSV.sublime-color-scheme  
// Rainbow CSV will auto-generate color theme with high-contrast colors to make CSV columns more distinguishable.  
// You can disable this setting and manually customize Rainbow CSV color scheme at `Packages/User/RainbowCSV.sublime-color-scheme`, you can use the following [RainbowCSV.sublime-color-scheme](https://github.com/mechatroner/sublime_rainbow_csv/blob/master/RainbowCSV.sublime-color-scheme) file as a starting point for your customizations. 
// Do NOT manually customize Packages/User/RainbowCSV.sublime-color-scheme without disabling this setting, the plugin will just rewrite it in that case.
// This option has effect only if "use_custom_rainbow_colors" is set to true
"auto_adjust_rainbow_colors": true,

This error appeared when I installed the package. It seems to be related. But I don't have any leads as to what caused it, or what to do about it.

Error loading syntax file "Packages/rainbow_csv/pregenerated_grammars/CSV(Rainbow).sublime-syntax": Unable to read Packages/rainbow_csv/pregenerated_grammars/CSV(Rainbow).sublime-syntax
Sublime Text Ver. 4126

I'm going to say that since you are at Sublime Text Ver. 4126 and the current latest version of Sublime Text is 4180 that there is a version issue. I would suggest opening an issue here Rainbow CSV issues.
